# Отменить действие e.preventDefault();

Tags: javascript, form, события, input

Есть `input checkbox`. Необходимо ставить галочку только если была нажата клавиша Shift хотя бы один раз.
Выбираем `input`. Проверяем нажатие `Shift`.

```js
    let box = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    let shiftKey = false;

    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      if(e.keyCode === 16){ return shiftKey = true}
    })
```

`e.preventDefault()` убирает галочку, даже когда `e.target.setAttribute('checked','');`

```js
    box.forEach(function(v,i,a) {
        a[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(shiftKey === true) {
                e.target.setAttribute('checked','');
            }
        });
    });
```

В консоли `checked` ставится. [image: введите сюда описание изображения].
Получается `input` с `checked`, но в браузере эта галочка не отображается.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, вам не нужно сравнивать значение, которое содержит true или false с true.
Вызов `e.preventDefault()` не позволит переключить чекбокс, поэтому его стоит вызвать, если клавиша shift не была нажата ни разу.

```
box.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (!shiftKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```